# disabling images when a if is worked in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to disable images in Chrome, but the current approach I've taken seems to disable reCAPTCHA as well. What I'm aiming for is to disable images only after successfully logging in. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Initialize Chrome with the given options
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Check if login is successful
if login_success:
    # Add argument to disable images
    chrome_options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
```

Comment: I wrote a sample code. there is no problem with the original code.

Comment: mine is not solved

Comment: ok, you haven't provided any details. if your conditional correctly triggering, is the argument added to chrome options? 
You have debugged the program and verified that the conditional executes and the argument is added right?

Comment: Can you really add arguments after you've already started Chrome? I think arguments are only checked when the browser is starting.